# Mongoid: How to chain eager loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, eager-loading

I have three models: Project, LineItem, and Spec

Project has many line items 
Project has many specs

I figured out how to eager load Project in a LineItem query:

```
LineItem.all.includes(:project)
```

but I can't seem to be able to get the eager loaded projects to also eager load their specs. How does one chain such eager loads in Mongoid?

Thank you!

Comment: Nik did you ever figure out an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`mongoid_includes` should answer that for you https://github.com/ElMassimo/mongoid_includes

Comment: This is not maintained anymore (last commit was 2 years ago) and it doesn't support mongoid 7. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

If it is so important to be eager loading, perhaps you should consider embedding those specs. I know this is not an answer to your question, but it may be a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Rails doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

```
LineItem.all.includes(:project => :specs)
# or
LineItem.all.includes({project: :specs})
```

Comment: You missed the mongoid tag, Mongoid and ActiveRecord are very different things.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that the hard way...
The doc for Mongoid 2 stipulates that it only supports one level deep eager loading. I'll try to see if it's still the case with mongoid 4.